# Image not getting displayed properly on splash screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen

I am designing a splash screen for my app and the image I am using for it is not getting displayed properly. I am attaching the picture I am using and how it is getting displayed here along with the code of the .xml file of the splash screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00abd4" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo1" />
```

[Picture I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtmIZ.jpg)

[How it's getting displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfg9g.png)

Comment: Try setting `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to `match_parent`.

Comment: In which drawable folder do you have it?

Comment: @Stefan There's a folder inside drawable which contains 4 sizes of the picture.

Comment: @Lal Not working with that too

Comment: in mdpi - hdpi - xhdpi - xxhdpi ? Because if you only use the default drawable map, it will be scaled en may be too big

Comment: Which one to use out of mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi?

Comment: How is the layout file you've provided being displayed?  Is it included by another layout file, and if so could you provide the including file?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00abd4" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo1" />
```

Comment: if you are using only these many lines of code you provided in xml, then it will work, If you have more things below it. check that...

Comment: This is the entire xml code for the splash screen. Just add the closing tag of RelativeLayout in the end.

Comment: then your image is smaller,

Comment: android:background="@drawable/logo1"

Comment: Okay. Let me try this. Also, the resolution of the pic is 1600x900 pixels

Comment: and if you dont want to crop you image as android does, use this,   android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: It's working now. The image's resolution was too high.